# Is there a way where we could do phrase proximity search using the lucene core libraries

Tags: lucene, proximity

I need to perform a proximity search between few phrases. The number of phrases are not known before hand. User can enter any number of phrases and can give his own slop. I need to support the nested phrase proximity search queries too. 
For example of the search queries I am looking at is: 
             "letter comes" slop "agitated employees".
             "letter comes" slop "agitated employees" slop "worried about salaries".
             "letter comes" slop "agitated slop "phrase1 slop phrase2 slop phrase3" slop empl"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot perform nested proximity searches. A kludge might be to create a phrase combining all terms with a large slop, say the sum of the individual slops:

```
("letter comes"~3 "agitated employees"~4 "worried about salaries"~1)
 AND ("letter comes agitated employees worried about salaries"~8)
```

(above assumes that your default operator is OR). I would play around with the combination phrase slop to see if I could get close to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5205/) patch by Tim Allison will help your use case. It provides recursive phrase queries and some other functionalities too.